# PostgreSQL: How to multiply two columns and display result in same query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that it's select statement is this:

```
select Greatest(p.price,0) as newprice, sum(q.qty) as qty
from ....
```

it gives me:

```
     newprice qty
      10      1
      0       1
      100     2
      1       2
```

I want to multiply newprice  with qty to get:

```
    newprice  qty   result
      10      1      10
      0       1      0
      100     2     200
      1       2      2
```

When I try to do `select Greatest(p.price,0) as newprice, sum(q.qty) as qty, newprice * qty` it says

```
ERROR: column "newprice" does not exist
```

I don't really need this extra column.

what i really want is : `SUM(Greatest(p.price,0) * SUM(q.qty))`  which should give the value `212` but It says `ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested`

Basically all I need is to multiply two columns and sum the result.
I know I can use CTE something similar to what is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437704/multiplying-two-columns-which-have-been-calculated-on-a-case-statement) but I'm wondering if there is an easier way with less code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just repeat what you wrote:

```
select Greatest(p.price,0) as newprice,
       sum(q.qty) as qty,
       Greatest(p.price,0) * sum(q.qty) as result
from ...
```

or, you can wrap your *select statement* to *temporary derived table* ([PostgreSQL: using a calculated column in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query))

```
select tmp.newprice,
       tmp.qty,
       tmp.newprice * tmp.qty as result
from (
    select Greatest(p.price,0) as newprice,
           sum(q.qty) as qty
    from ...
) as tmp
```

Answer (score 4):

Query should be like this :

```
select *, newprice*qty from
(
    select Greatest(p.price,0) as newprice, sum(q.qty) as qty
    from ....
) T
```

OR

```
select Greatest(p.price,0) as newprice, sum(q.qty) as qty, Greatest(p.price,0)*sum(q.qty) as result
from ....
```

UPDATE :

you are using `group by` in your query (I presumed because of aggregation) and in order to find sum(newprice*qty), you will need a sub select :

```
select sum(newprice*qty) from
(
    select Greatest(p.price,0) as newprice, sum(q.qty) as qty
    from ....
) T
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid this... as I will have to wrap it with another select to get the final value (in my example 212)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select sum(price*qty) as result
from yourtable;
```